# display and load html before js files using express.static

Tags: javascript, express

I am having a hard time displaying my home.html file contents onto the browser when I use express.static. My directory and file layout is:

```
dir main
    -server.js
    dir subMain
      dir routing
        -routes.js
      dir public
        -home.html
        -list.html
```

Code for server.js

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//Renamed the path with the correct directory names
var htmlRoutes = require('./subMain/routing/routes.js')(app, path, express);
```

Code for routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, path, express){

    //This path.join should lead to 'subMain'
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '..')));
    //This path.join should lead to 'app'
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '..', '..')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '..', 'public')));

    app.listen(10003, function(){
        console.log('connected on 10003')
    })
}
```

Currently I have two problems.

1) I am trying to use express.static instead of sendFile because, in my home.html file I have a link to jquery library and to routes.js; when I tried doing sendFile, the jquery selector $ was not being recognized because js was loading before html. That is why I am trying to use express.static to load all files by doing what I have above.

2)I keep getting the message 'cannot GET /' in the browser. Even when I take out the first two lines of code that use app.use(express.static), and just have the one that leads to the html in the directory 'public', I still get this message. How can I properly display home.html and load it completly before my js file does so that I can use jquery selector to have a click event for a button that will make an Ajax call to GET /list and display list.html

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the static folders at the top level of your app (server.js ?) and once for all.

Comment: So you mean all the folders I am using express.static with should be in the folder 'main'? My project requires me to follow the layout put above

Comment: Not at all. Just, the declaration of public folders should be done at the top level of your app.